# get EditText maximum text area

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

EditText has this inner area that the text is only placed there, regardless if it's a scrolling editText or not. I tried to get this parameter by doing this, but this doesn't seem like a good solution:

```
        val textAreaWidth = editText.measuredWidth - editText.marginStart - editText.marginEnd - editText.paddingStart - editText.paddingEnd
```

How can you get this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions for EditText is not something that comes by default. You give them your own dimension which can be of a fixed height/width or can be of length equivalent to text size (by setting height-width as wrap-content).

You can define them in the layout file(the xml one) and read the layout in your fragment or you can define the widget programmatically but the logical way it is defined remains the same.

You can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) link for better understanding.